# UML: Derived class instantiates other derived class of same base

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Given the following class setup:

```
B: base
D1: derived from B
D2: derived from B
... (many more)
Dn: derived from B
```

---

**Edit**

The purpose of those classes is to decode a packet from TCP/IP into various protocols (IP, UDP, TCP, many other application protocols). Each protocol is handled by an other class to rebuild the packet structure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRAhH.jpg)

[image: ethernet frame]

Class `B` is an abstract decoder class with virtual method `decode()`.

Classes `D#` overload `decode()` specific to their protocol specification.

E.g. `DecoderIP` calls `DecoderUDP` ...

---

How would I depict in a class diagram that each derived class `D#` can instantiate an other derived class `D#` (association) without overloading the diagram with edges?

Currently my diagram looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HsBE.png) to fit on A4 paper.

[image: uml class diagram]

Comment: You should explain what you intend with those classes. Without you won't get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I added the purpose of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You would not describe `n` D-classes unless you have a concrete case where you need those. Instead you have concrete applications where you use the decoder. Namely these are IP, UDP, etc. So you write your class model like:

[image]

Your decoders in your picture are not derived from one base class, but the are rather a stack build on top of each other. I doubt they will all use the same `decode` method. So that is probably a logical error in your thinking. What should that `decode` method do? Decode "something" and deliver "what?".

Comment: [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?context=class-diagrams) says: "Generalization relationships that reference the same general classifier can also be connected together in the 'shared target style.' ". In the `decode` method, the bytedata of that protocol is read and analysed. The decoded result is delivered to a controller class.

Comment: How you bend the generalization connector is at your own wish. Still "decoded result to CC" does not make sense. Each specialized decoder has its own context. There is not much general between a UDP and a TCP decoder. The decode is the interpretation of content which is very little semantic to make a generalization. The main part is how they react on the decoded data.

Comment: In the call stack the classes are indeed build on top of each other. `decode` is virtual, so it has to be implemented on a derived class. The base class offers methods for reading bytes and delivering results what every decoder needs.

Comment: Consider using an <<interface>> instead of a Generalization. Seems to make much more sense.